# Video is not getting transcoded

Tags: video, drupal-7, zencoder, localtunnel

I am using Video Module in Drupal 7 and utilizing Zencoder as an option for encoding videos.
I use http://progrium.com/localtunnel/  to make localhost servers public in internet.

I followed following steps to configure localtunnel in my machine

- Downloaded Ruby/Ruby Gems and generate ssh keys for hosting localhost
  in public.
- My Apache server is running on port 80. So I run this command

  localtunnel -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 80
- It ask for passphrase and I gave it.
- Then it shows following message:-

  This localtunnel service is brought to you by Twilio. Port 80 is now accessible from
   http://5557.localtunnel.com"

When I give

```
http://5557.localtunnel.com/VideoSample/postback/jobs
```

as value in Postback URL of Transcoder option in Administration » Configuration » Media » Video then the configuration is also getting saved.

Now I upload the video in Video content type. It gives the following message after node is saved.

This video is currently being processed. Please wait.

When I check my account at Zencoder it says the status as "Processing". After some time it change the status to Fail and gives the following message:-

We tried to download the file at

```
http://localhost/VideoSample/sites/default/files/videos/original/big_buck_bunny.mp4, but it was not there. Get more information in the documentation.
```

The folder videos/original has given public access. Please let me know where I am doing mistake or what permission or steps to perform to get the encoded file back to website.

Answer (score 0):

Zencoder needs to be able to access the file over the internet in order to be able to download it, so localhost isn't going to work. You might be able to use localtunnel.com again, but my guess is the download speed is going to be painfully slow.

Just to test, you may want to try pushing your code to a development server online, or set Drupal to upload your files to a service such as S3 for Zencoder to access.